# How can I change both names and file types of multiple files at once on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, matlab, file-type

I need to change both file names and file type of multiple files at once, but I'm not sure how to do that.

For example, I have files like A.1, A.2, A.3 ... I want them to be A1.dat, A2.dat, A3.dat...

Furthermore, can I convert A.1, A.2, A.3 to A1.mat, A2.mat, A3.mat, which are MATLAB data file format in arrays?

Thank you in advance.

Arnold

Comment: Renaming should be straightforward - whether (and how) you can convert them to (valid) .mat files will depend on what they actually contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you can find the Perl rename script. It may be installed automatically. If you can find it, it accepts sed script. For renaming files, great! Allows regular expressions

```
rename 's/$/.dat/' A*
```

Will change files beginning with A by appending .dat. The $ indicates end of name. If you want rename to mat, same idea.

The sed Regular expression can be much more elaborate.

Beware, Fedora ships a different rename utility, not nearly so good. The Perl one I suggest has existed a long time, an original Larry Wall classic from 1997.